# combining null layout with card layout [java]

Tags: java, swing, layout, cardlayout

I'm trying to combine the cardlayout function with the null layout.
However when i try to run the program it doesn't work. The buttons do not appear at the boundries i tell them. Am i doing something wrong or is the whole concept of using them both wrong?

```
public class CardLayoutTest extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel cardPanel, jp1, jp2, buttonPanel;
private JLabel jl1, jl2;
private JButton btn1, btn2;
private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

public CardLayoutTest() {
    setTitle("Test med CardLayout");
    setSize(400, 300);
    Insets insets = getInsets();
    cardPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    cardPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
    jp1 = new JPanel();
    jp2 = new JPanel();
    jl1 = new JLabel("Card 1");
    jl2 = new JLabel("Card 2");
    jp1.add(jl1);
    jp2.add(jl2);
    cardPanel.add(jp1, "1");
    cardPanel.add(jp2, "2");
    btn1 = new JButton("Show Card 1");
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "1");
        }
    });
    btn2 = new JButton("Show Card 2");
    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "2");
        }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(btn1);
    buttonPanel.add(btn2);
    add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(buttonPanel, null);

    Dimension size1 = btn1.getPreferredSize();
    btn1.setBounds(100 + insets.left, 100 + insets.top,
                 size1.width, size1.height);

    Dimension size = btn2.getPreferredSize();
    btn2.setBounds(210 + insets.left, 130 + insets.top,
                 size.width, size.height);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            CardLayoutTest frame = new CardLayoutTest();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Ahh, in stead of `add(buttonPanel, null);`, maybe try `add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` - before you jump down my throat spouting something about `null` layouts, I think you will need to understand what a `null` layout actually is, because this isn't it

Comment: You also have to recognise that a container will rely on it's children to provide appropriate sizing hints, which none of your code does, so `buttonPanel` could have no way to know how large it needs to be to occupy the requirements of it's children.  This is where things like, appropriate layouts, layout constraints and borders come into play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am i doing something wrong

Yes, assuming that a `null` layout could help you (but not understand what a `null` layout is and the work you would be required to take over from the layout management API)

> or is the whole concept of using them both wrong?

In short, yes.  99.99% of time your think you need a `null` layout, you don't and even in that 0.01% times that you "might", you probably don't

So, what's the answer?  Surprisingly, use an appropriate layout manager and stop worrying about "pixel perfect" layouts, they are an illusion.  Modern computer systems run on a verity of hardware and software which changes aspects of the UI which will change the way component need to interact or be sized.

While you might be considering to run this on only one OS, even then, the hardware and software drivers and operating settings can change the size of the fonts, font metrics and DPI all of which will effect the amount of space that components need to be properly rendered.

Instead, focus on the work flow and usability of the UI to maximise the user experience.

So, based on my (limited) understand of your problem, I used a `GridBagLayout` on the `buttonPanel` instead to "mimic" your expected results.

[image: Example]

```
buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//...
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.insets = new Insets(100, 0, 0, 0);

buttonPanel.add(btn1, gbc);

gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
gbc.gridx++;
gbc.gridy++;
buttonPanel.add(btn2, gbc);
```

Layout managers can be a little difficult to get your head around to start with, but they are immensely powerful tools.  I've spent my entire career using all the built in layout managers, one 3rd party layout and a couple of custom layout managers I built to solve particular issues. I've never felt the need to fall back to `null` layouts, I find them limiting, they require an enormous amount time and work to maintain and are generally lazy

Comment: Thanks for you amazing help! I will do some more research on GridBagLayouts then.